# System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. During Test automation execution

Tags: c#, automation

It would be great if somebody helps me in solving below issue that I am facing during automation execution:

I am trying to bring in test case looping based on number of lines in the excel. I am using Data-driven capability in visual studio to achieve this.
This works perfectly in Visual studio environment when i execute in "Test Explorer". But, when I build this project’s DLL and copy to the working folder of the automation tool (Where it picks for execution), below error is triggered:

*System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Please see the below code snippet:

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xlsx)};dbq=J:\\Automation_Working_Directory\\Automation_Files_Demo\\Test_Report_01Base.xlsx;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", "SrsReportRunController_Dialog$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_Report_01()
    {
        #region Fetch data from Excel file

        string fromDate = TestContext.DataRow["From date"].ToString();
        string startDate = TestContext.DataRow["Report period start date"].ToString();
        string toDate = TestContext.DataRow["To date"].ToString();

        #endregion Fetch data from Excel file

        Application.Control.TextBox().SetValue(fromDate);}
```

When i am trying to use the "fromDate" value to enter in the application, I am getting NullReferenceExecption.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add try-catch in your code, which will help you identifying exact error line number

I think maybe `ToString()` is causing this issue in case of DataRow value is `null`.

Try using [Convert Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) this will help to avoid exception to some extent

```
 public void Test_Report_01()
 {
     try{
         #region Fetch data from Excel file

        string fromDate = Convert.ToString(TestContext.DataRow["From date"]);
        string startDate = Convert.ToString(TestContext.DataRow["Report period start date"]);
        string toDate = Convert.ToString(TestContext.DataRow["To date"]);

        #endregion Fetch data from Excel file

        Application.Control.TextBox().SetValue(fromDate);
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         Console.WriteLine(e.toString());
     }
}
```

Comment: The code is perfect, since this executes without issues in Visual studio environment. I am getting issue while i am using this DLL for execution from an automation tool.

Comment: Your code is not handled for runtime exceptions. Adding try-catch will prevent from crashing your application due to the unhandled exception.

Comment: Look for details in exception log, you will come to know why it's throwing that

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used try-catch, the code snippet shown is for illustration purpose of how i am using Data-driven concept. "Application.Control.Textbox().SetValue(fromDate);" line is for letting know the place where the data read from excel is used.